# Why is Python 3 is considerably slower than Python 2?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpython

I've been trying to understand why Python 3 is actually taking much time compared with Python 2 in certain situations, below are few cases I've verified from python 3.4 to python 2.7.

Note: I've gone through some of the questions like [Why is there no xrange function in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014310)  and  [loop in python3 much slower than python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678127)  and [Same code slower in Python3 as compared to Python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911122), but I feel that I didn't get the actual reason behind this issue.

I've tried this piece of code to show how it is making difference:

```
MAX_NUM = 3*10**7

# This is to make compatible with py3.4.
try:
    xrange
except:
    xrange = range


def foo():
    i = MAX_NUM
    while i> 0:
        i -= 1

def foo_for():
    for i in xrange(MAX_NUM):
        pass
```

When I've tried running this programme with py3.4 and py2.7 I've got below 
results.

Note: These stats came through a `64 bit` machine with `2.6Ghz` processor and calculated the time using `time.time()` in single loop.

```
Output : Python 3.4
-----------------
2.6392083168029785
0.9724123477935791

Output: Python 2.7
------------------
1.5131521225
0.475143909454
```

I really don't think that there has been changes applied to `while` or `xrange` from 2.7 to 3.4, I know `range` has been started acting as to `xrange` in py3.4 but as documentation says

> `range()` now behaves like `xrange()` used to behave, except it works with values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists.

this means change from `xrange` to `range` is very much equal to a name change but working with arbitrary values.

I've verified disassembled byte code as well.

Below is the disassembled byte code for function `foo()`:

```
Python 3.4:
--------------- 

 13           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (MAX_NUM)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 14           6 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 35)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             15 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

 15          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             27 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE

python 2.7
-------------

 13           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (MAX_NUM)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 14           6 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 35)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             15 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

 15          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             27 INPLACE_SUBTRACT    
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

And below is the disassembled byte code for function `foo_for()`:

```
Python: 3.4

 19           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (MAX_NUM)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 20          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE


Python: 2.7
-------------

 19           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (MAX_NUM)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 20          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

If we compare both the byte codes they've produced the same disassembled byte code.

Now I'm wondering what change from 2.7 to 3.4 is really causing this huge change in execution time in the given piece of code.

Comment: post the full code and the measurement method

Comment: Running this just once with the *whole interpreter setup* won't tell you anything. Use `timeit.timeit()` to run time trials instead.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The difference is in the implementation of the `int` type. Python 3.x uses the arbitrary-sized integer type (`long` in 2.x) exclusively, while in Python 2.x for values up to `sys.maxint` a simpler `int` type is used that uses a simple C `long` under the hood.

Once you limit your loops to *`long`* integers, Python 3.x is faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> MAX_NUM = 3*10**3
>>> def bar():
...     i = MAX_NUM + sys.maxsize
...     while i > sys.maxsize:
...         i -= 1
...
```

Python 2:

```
>>> timeit(bar, number=10000)
5.704327821731567
```

Python 3:

```
>>> timeit(bar, number=10000)
3.7299320790334605
```

I used `sys.maxsize` as `sys.maxint` was dropped from Python 3, but the integer value is basically the same.

The speed difference in Python 2 is thus limited to the first (2 ** 63) - 1 integers on 64-bit, (2 ** 31) - 1 integers on 32 bit systems.

Since you cannot use the `long` type with `xrange()` on Python 2, I did not include a comparison for that function.

Comment: Is there any reason you would not want to optimize for integers below 2**63?  They seem to be the most frequently used...

Comment: @thebjorn: the simplification of using one `int` type was more important. Besides, if you are doing `for` loops over that large a range you are probably doing something wrong *anyway*.

Comment: But doesn't this choice make all integer calculations on e.g. array indexes etc. slower too? It seems that other languages (Smalltalk, Lisp, Haskell, Java) go to some lengths in order to optimize the boxing/unboxing of integers, are those optimizations superfluous in a language like Python?

Comment: @thebjorn: sequences are explicitly limited to `sys.maxsize` anyway and for up to 2**30 (one digit) the code is highly optimised to just return the first digit from the Python `int` object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It still doesn't give the same performance, as the OP's tests show.

Comment: @quant_dev: Of course those tests don't give the same performance. I never said they could be made to give the same performance. When you are using *large integers* past `sys.maxint` you get the same performance *in Python 2* because the same codepaths are involved then.