# Python 3: Loops, list comprehension and map slower compared to Python 2?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am currently learning Python 3 and thought some speed comparison could be neat. Thus, I created some in-place and some temporary list functions, which simply add 1 to a long list of integers.

However, the results were really surprising to me...it seems that Python 3 is slower in every use case: different tested for loops, a while loop, the map function, and list comprehensions.

Of course (see the code below) it just comparison of in-place list mutations or loops that build up and return a temporary list...so e.g. the "standard" map of Python 3, that just creates an iterator, is still fast, **but** at some point one would always like to print, write or somehow visualize the data. Hence, something like `list(map())` should be relatively common in Python 3?!

**What am I missing here?**

Is Python 3 really slower than Python 2 for loops, comprehensions and map? If so, why?

---

**Python 3.4 timings**:

```
> python3.4 func_speed_tests.py
list_comprehension.........1.2785s
for_loop...................1.9988s
for_loop_append............1.8471s
for_loop_range.............1.7585s
while_loop.................2.2539s
calc_map...................2.0763s
```

**Python 2.7 timings**:

```
> python2.7 func_speed_tests.py
list_comprehension.........0.9472s
for_loop...................1.2821s
for_loop_append............1.5663s
for_loop_range.............1.3101s
while_loop.................2.1914s
calc_map...................1.9101s
```

---

Here is the **code**:

```
import timeit
from random import shuffle

# generate a long list of integers
mlst = list(range(0, 1000000))

# randomly sort the list
shuffle(mlst)

# number of benchmark passes
n = 10


#####################
# functions to time #
#####################

def list_comprehension(lst):
    return [x + 1 for x in lst]


def for_loop(lst):
    for k, v in enumerate(lst):
        lst[k] = v + 1


def for_loop_append(lst):
    tmp = []
    for item in lst:
        tmp.append(item + 1)


def for_loop_range(lst):
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        lst[k] += 1
    return lst


def while_loop(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    tmp = []
    while it:
        try:
            tmp.append(next(it)+1)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return tmp


def calc_map(lst):
    lst = map(lambda x: x + 1, lst)
    return list(lst)


############################################
# helper functions for timing and printing #
############################################   

def print_time(func_name):
    print("{:.<25}{:.>8.4f}s".format(func_name, timer(func_name)))


def timer(func):
    return timeit.timeit(stmt="{}(mlst)".format(func),
                         setup="from __main__ import mlst, {}".format(func),
                         number=n)

#################
# run the tests #
#################

print_time("list_comprehension")
print_time("for_loop")
print_time("for_loop_append")
print_time("for_loop_range")
print_time("while_loop")
print_time("calc_map")
```

Comment: are you using `range()` for both python 2 and 3? or `xrange()` for python2 and `range()` for python3?

Comment: Yes, I am running the exact same script. That's why I am using `list(map())` for example, so that it is compatible with Python 2 and 3, and does the same thing in both languages.

Comment: In fact, since `range()` generates a list rather than an iterator in Python 2, I thought at least the loops using `range()` should be slower in Python 2...but everything is faster o.O

Comment: @ascenator The creation of the list using `range()` in Python 2 is slower but once the list is there, iterating over the list is faster since it’s internally just a sequencial memory access. The generator solution has an overhead for the iterator protocol, making it likely a bit slower.

Comment: @poke ah ok, so the *space complexity* for `range()` in Python 2 is higher, because of the full list in the memory but the *time complexity* is lower, because the list iteration is faster than the iterator?! Hence, Python 2 is faster but uses more memory in those cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548680/why-is-python-3-is-considerably-slower-than-python-2 – but in general, there is no clear indication: Some things are slower due to how Python 3 works (e.g. `long` being the new `int`, `unicode` being the new `str`), but there are also parts that are faster. It’s difficult to compare, and I don’t think small functional benchmarks will ultimately help you decide.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Python3 is slightly slower that Python2. Check with [pystone benchmark](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/272bao/python_34_slow_compared_to_27_whats_your_mileage/). If speed is of concern stick with [Python 2.7.0 Release](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) which has better third party package support.

Comment: Ok, thanks. At least we have something to go on with this. Do you have any additional sources or ideas yourself *why* this is happening?