# Python 3 is slower than Python 2 in RFE

Tags: python, python-3.x, rfe

I'm new at python sklearn. Since I moved to Python 3, my code starts to take more time to run RFECV... It passed from 5h to almost 15h to run several RFE CV. 
I found this link, but I guess that the case is different from mine: [Why is Python 3 is considerably slower than Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548680/why-is-python-3-is-considerably-slower-than-python-2)

Here is an example of the code:

```
for fs_method, fs_dict in fs_models.items():
    print(fs_method)
    pickle_dict[fs_method] = dict()
    pipe = pipeline_classifier(fs_dict['clf'])

for score in fs_scorers:
    print (score)
    feature_selector_cv = skf.RFECV(pipe,
                                    cv=kf,
                                    step=rfecv_step,
                                    scoring=score.replace('-', '_'),
                                    n_jobs=-1
                                    )
    feature_selector_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Can it be caused by different versions of sklearn?